# Swift Get Value for NSDictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I Xcode, I can see the value for `item.body()`. and then iterate each of the user. but I can not get the value for `users`. Please see the attached image. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: This looks like json. Have a look at https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON in general for a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

form item.body() you are getting a dictionary of [NSObject:AnyObject]. You have to cast that to what you expect the dictionary to look like. I assume here it's [String:AnyObject] so do:

```
let myStringDict = item.body as? [String:AnyObject]
```

the you can access they value for the key "users" like:

```
myStringDict?["users"]
```